# How to use SelectField for Flask and retrieve multiple values

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I have to design a webpage in Flask. In this WebPage, I have to prompt the user to select multiple field like branch, name, and retrieve a text field from the user.

The following is my form class (forms.py):

```
class ProjectSelect(Form):
   branch = SelectField('Branch')
   name = SelectField('Name)
   comments = TextField('Comments')
```

My View.py is as follows:

```
  @app.route('/user/<email>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
  def user(email):
    branch_list = Dummy.query.all()
    name_list = Dummy1.query.all()
    form = ProjectSelect()
    form.branch.choices = branch_list
    form.name.choices = name_list
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       # How to get data??
       return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('index.html')
```

Currently, I have not designed the html template for this setup. I'm not sure how to code that since I'm new to both HTML and Flask. As the view suggests, I need to implement 2 select fields based on branch_list and name_list. I need a single submit button to select data from the two selectfield and from one textfield and I need to retrieve the data back to my view.py. How do I do this?

As a next step, the name select field is dependent on the value selected on the branch select field. How do I dynamically update the selectfield in html to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked several questions in this post.

1) To get data (after `if form.validate_on_submit():`), you'll use something like:

```
`if form.validate_on_submit():
       branch = form.branch.data
       name = form.name.data
       # do something with branch and name
       return redirect(url_for('index'))`
```

2) Your view should look something like this:

```
`<form method="post">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.branch.label }}{{ form.branch }}
{{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name }}
{{ form.comments.label}} {{ form.comments }}
{{ form.submit }}
</form>`
```

3) You are missing the submit field in your `ProjectSelect` class definition. You need:

```
`submit = SubmitField("Submit")`
```

Note: Be sure your import statement (at the top of the file) has this:

`from wtforms import SubmitField, SelectField`

4) In your `views.py`, on the last line, where you have `return render_template('index.html')`, you need to pass in the form object:

`return render_template('index.html', form=form)`

5) To implement a `SelectField` with predefined choices, use this:

`name = SelectField('Name', choices=name_choices)`

Note: This assumes `name_choices` is defined as list like this:

name_choices = ['Choice One', 'Choice Two']

6) Your code sample has a syntax error in the `ProjectSelect` class:

[FIND]

`name = SelectField('Name)`

[REPLACE WITH]

`name = SelectField('Name')`

Comment: This is good! Now moving on, There is function validate_on_submit. Similarly, is there some function that is triggered when the user selects an option in the branch list? . I want this so that I can automatically update the name list based on the branch that is selected. If my understanding is right. validate_on_submit is triggered only after the submit button is clicked right?

Comment: @Django that's correct. `validate_on_submit` is only triggered upon submission (in the HTML context). You'll want to use JavaScript to maintain a list of possible choices based on the branch that's selected (e.g. if branch is X show Y choices). Then, you could implement a custom validator within your form class to make sure the values that are received match what is expected for the branch that is chosen.